# Find radius of largest circle within ellipse $\frac{x^2}{9} + \frac{y^2}4 = 1$ with their intersection only at $(3,0)$

Tags: geometry, contest-math, circles, conic-sections

An ellipse is defined by the equation $$\frac{x^2}{9} + \frac{y^2}4 = 1$$

Compute the radius of the largest circle that is internally tangent to the ellipse at $(3,0),$ and intersects the ellipse only at $(3,0).$

How can I write an equation for the largest circle within this ellipse if its equation is given? Is there a property or theorem I'm missing? Is there another way to solve?

Comment: This is asking for the radius of curvature of the ellipse. Do you know about that?

Comment: Find the largest radius for which the intersection between ellipse and circle is a single point.

Comment: Mahika Please edit your post to cite the source of this question.

Comment: It's hard to say what you might be "missing" since we don't know what you're supposed to know. The source of the question could help in that regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the equation of the circle $(x-a)^2+y^2 =(3-a)^2$ that passes the point $(3,0)$. Then, substitute $y^2$ into $\frac{x^2}{9} + \frac{y^2}4 = 1$ to get

$$\frac59 x^2 -2ax +6a-5=0$$

Since the two shapes has only one common point $(3,0)$, the discriminate of above quadratic equation is zero, which yields $a= \frac53$ and hence the radius $3-a= \frac43$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4}=1\implies y'=-\frac{4x}{9y}\implies y''=\frac{4(xy'-y)}{9y^2}$$
The [radius of curvature, R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_curvature) i.e. radius of circular arc that best approximates the given ellipse at the point $(3,0)$ will be the radius of largest circle which internally touches the ellipse at point $(3,0)$ only, is given as
$$R=\left|\frac{(1+y'^2)^{3/2}}{y''}\right|=\left|\frac{\left(16x^2+81y^2\right)^{3/2}}{36(4x^2+9y^2)}\right|$$
Substituting $x=3$ & $y=0$ in above equation, radius $R$ of the largest circle touching ellipse internally at a single point $(3,0)$, is given as
$$\color{blue}{R}=\left|\frac{\left(16(3)^2+81(0)^2\right)^{3/2}}{36(4(3)^2+9(0)^2)}\right|=\color{blue}{\frac43}$$